# Faddeev-Popov Gauge Fixing Procedure

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, path-integral, yang-mills, gauge

I want to know that does $F^{a}[A_{\mu}] = 0$ condition used in Faddeev-Popov Quantization has unique solution $A_{\mu}$ or is it $F^{a}[A^{\theta}_{\mu}] = 0$ should have unique $\theta$ as solution where $A^{\theta}_{\mu}$ is gauge transformed $A_{\mu}$ with parameter $\theta^{a}(x)$ (but then won't $\theta = 0$ is also one of the solution). If this is the case that will mean that $F^{a}[A_{\mu}] = 0$ initially does not exactly fixed the redundancy. I have this confusion because during the process we take
$1 = \int \Pi_{x, a}d\theta^{a}(x)\delta(F^{a}[A^{\theta}_{\mu}])\det[\delta F^{a}[A^{\theta}_{\mu}(x)]/\delta\theta^{b}(y)]$ (and prove that this is gauge invariant) and insert this in the path integral extracting out $\int \Pi_{x, a}d\theta^{a}(x)$ volume element and leaving path integral as
$\int D[A]\det[\delta F^{a}[A^{\theta}_{\mu}(x)]/\delta\theta^{b}(y)]\delta(F^{a}[A^{\theta}_{\mu}])\exp{iS}$ and now we again gauge transform with $-\theta^{a}(x)$ parameter to remove dependence on $\theta^{a}(x)$ from the path integral. Now my question is now while evaluating $\det$ at $\theta = 0$,
$\det[\delta F^{a}[A^{\theta}_{\mu}(x)]/\delta\theta^{b}(y)]_{\theta=0}$, can we also use $F^{a}[A_{\mu}] = 0$ as one of the condition in evaluating this determinant (we cannot use this if our starting $A_{\mu}$ does not satisfy gauge fixing condition $F^{a}[A^{\theta}_{\mu}] = 0$, assuming $\theta$ is not zero).